# VSCode debugger not working with recursive function

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04 and having trouble stepping through a recursive function.

The application is NodeJS, no browser.

Run via `npm start`

```
"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/try2.js"
```

Stepping through this non-recursive functions works fine.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name // {1}
  }
  get name() {
    // {2}
    return this._name
  }
  set name(value) {
    // {3}
    this._name = value
  }
}

let lotrChar = new Person('Frodo')
lotrChar.name = 'Gandalf' // {5}
lotrChar._name = 'Sam' // {6}
console.log(lotrChar._name)
```

However, with this function, with a breakpoint on both the first and second `if` statements, when debugging

- the breakpoints disappear
- the code breaks on the function declaration
- press 'step-into'
- the code exits with no additional stepping

```js
function factorial(n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (n === 1 || n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

const a = factorial(5)
console.log('a', a)
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**",
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/try2.js",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I made a short video to show the problem.

https://youtu.be/fPWffC0BUqw